# function is not working properly in Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt4

I am making a simple GUI program to change bootanimation of a android phone but from last 4 days I am facing a problem and I don't know whats is reason, here is my code

```
void MainWindow::bootanim1()
{   
    QProcess rootboot;

    QStringList path6,boottarget;
    path6<<ui->lineEdit_6->text();

    boottarget<<path6<<" /system/media";
    ui->textBrowser->clear();
    ui->textBrowser->setText("Remounting partitions...");
    rootboot.start("bbin\\adb shell su -c \"busybox mount -o remount,rw /system\"");
    rootboot.waitForFinished();
    ui->textBrowser->setText("\nInstalling bootanimation.zip");
    rootboot.start("bbin\\adb push ",boottarget);
    rootboot.waitForFinished();
    ui->textBrowser->setText("\nBootanimation has been changed! Try shutting down your phone to see new bootanimation");
}
```

This function is launched when a button is clicked but my problem is, this is not working! Secondly you can see in the code that to be more informative I have used a `textBrowser` to show user whats going on like Remounting partitions etc and the `lineEdit_6` is the `lineEdit` widget where user will paste the path of the bootanimation.zip. So my problem is when I click the button only this is shown

`Bootanimation has been changed! Try shutting down your phone to see new bootanimation`

And everything above it I think is getting skipped, I don't know why? can anyone give me some hint on what I am missing?

Comment: It is not "getting skipped", that's for sure.

Comment: So what do you think, why it doesn't work? My bootanimation doesn't get replaced. why? any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are mixing two different methods to give arguments to QProcess:

```
boottarget<<path6<<" /system/media";
rootboot.start("bbin\\adb push ",boottarget);
```

[First method](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qprocess.html#start-2) gives the program name and arguments in one QString.

[Second method](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qprocess.html#start) gives the arguments in a QStringList.

You are trying to give one argument ("push") in the program name string. It doesn't work, when the other arguments are given in a QStringList. The last argument also contains suspicious looking space in the beginning, although I don't know if it causes problems. Try this instead:

```
QStringList args;
args << "push" << path6 << "/system/media";
rootboot.start("bbin\\adb", args);
```

And path6 variable probably should be QString instead of QStringList.

Comment: OMG!!!!!! This actually works!!!!! Really Thanks a ton, you made my day. But a small problem still, I am still getting "Bootanimation has been changed! Try shutting down your phone to see new bootanimation" in the textBrowser and all that "Remounting Partition" and other textually informative stuff is not getting displayed, but the happy part is, this time bootanimation got replaced. Thank you!. Do you have any idea with textual part?

Comment: Kamil Klimek's answer about the eventloop is the correct answer for that. I don't know about Android, but I guess that those command lines are executed so fast that you wouldn't have time to see the messages anyway because you are replacing the whole text instead of just adding some new text. Probably you should also be checking the return values of start() functions so you could detect if there are any problems with the executed commands.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that everytime I used 

ui->textBrowser->setText("My Text");

previous text was cleared. So how to throw text without clearing previous lines so that later I can clear it manually using

ui->textBrowser->clear();

Comment: `ui->textBrowser->append("Installing bootanimation.zip");`

Comment: Many many Thank you! Now everything is working superfine!! You guys really ROCK!!

Answer (score 0):

Ui requires eventloop to refresh itself. When you do all changes in one function call, then only internal property change, and gui itself doesn't repaint. Use `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` right after each `ui->textBrowser->setText(...);`

Comment: Better yet, instead of `waitForFinished()`, `connect()` the `finished()` signal to a function with the remainder of the logic.

Comment: Ok so you mean to say that the necessary operations and commands are executed successfully right? Then why my bootanimation doesn't change?

Comment: I didn't say that all processes are launched successfully. I just said that ui needs to process some events to change. You must put some effort in checking why your processes doesn't work. You should check error code from QProcess and exit code from process itself. Read QProcess documentation